# IOS App not signing in with correct credentials using Automation Code

Tags: iphone, appium

IOS Configuration : Appium 1.3.4,Mac OS 10.9.4,Xcode 6.1.1,IOS 8.1 (iPhone 6) device
I was providing correct credentials in the Sign In Screen and tap on 'Sign In' button in the IOS App , it giving message as "Sign In Problem" , no issues with credentials , manually I am able to sign in using same credentials.

**below is code -** 
driver.findElementByXPath("//UIAApplication[1]/UIAWindow[2]/UIATableView[1]/UIATableCell[1]").sendKeys("testauto_111k@example.com");
driver.findElementByXPath("//UIAApplication[1]/UIAWindow[2]/UIATableView[1]/UIATableCell[2]").sendKeys("testpwd1");
 driver.findElementByXPath("//UIAApplication[1]/UIAWindow[2]/UIAButton[1]").click();

I was suspecting , password may not be taking correctly , then I have encrypted password and tried to enter as follows same "Sign In" problem encountered.
 String pass1 = "testpwd1";
byte[] encodedPwdBytes = Base64.encodeBase64(pass1.getBytes());
String pass2 = new String(encodedPwdBytes,"UTF-8"); // converting byte code to string and trying to sign in , still same issue.

driver.findElementByXPath("//UIAApplication[1]/UIAWindow[2]/UIATableView[1]/UIATableCell[2]").sendKeys(pass2);

appreciate your support in this.

Regards,
Kiran

Answer (score 0):

Try to use your code this way:

```
WebElement test = driver.findElement(By.XPath("//UIAApplication[1]/UIAWindow[2]/UIATableView[1]/UIATableCell[1]");
test.sendKeys("testauto_111k@example.com");
WebElement test1 = driver.findElement(By.XPath("//UIAApplication[1]/UIAWindow[2]/UIATableView[1]/UIATableCell[2]");
test1.sendKeys("testpwd1");
```

Comment: Thanks for your guidance , I have tried suggested approach. Same issue I am seeing "Sign In Problem" popup , in your approach I am seeing password as "testpwd1" , it is not in dot format. Can you suggest another approach?

Comment: sorry confused, its not in dot format? And it is going as testpwd1 right? i am misunderstood what exactly you are trying to achieve

Comment: For any application whenever we enter password , it should show in masked (for ex: *********) format , with your suggestion I am trying to enter username and password values in the App sign in screen. So I am seeing original text while entering password value. My Original issue , when I entered correct values , it is giving "Sign In Problem" dialog. I am suspecting it is not taking password as it should be compare to manual process. Hope I cleared your doubt. Can you suggest other alternate solution?

Comment: Hi Team, any support to me in this?

Answer (score 0):

As per other entries in GitHub , Appium 1.3.4 is not treating correctly Sign In text fields , hence there is breakage in the Sign In text fields process by Appium 1.3.4 and it seems to server side defect. After this read , I realized Appium 1.3.4 Inspector is incorrectly highlighting SignIn text fields and I was expecting that shown Xpath is correct and applying in the code for values entry. All though code is entering values in the fields but after Sign In process , giving popup invalid e-mail id although it is correct visually. I came to know Appium 1.3.1 is more stable and thought of tying with this one. I got worked out this way , XPath of Sign In fields shown by 1.3.1 Appium Inspector is appropriate and values are entered , Sign In successful. Same code run through Appium 1.3.4 , it worked out. In conclusion , although Appium 1.3.4 is showing Xpath of Sign In fields but those are incorrectly exposed by Appium Inspector and it needs to be fixed in this aspect to behave like Appium 1.3.1.
Thanks everyone who supported me in this one.